# SelectItem in UICollectionView on first Load

Tags: swift, select, uicollectionview, row, cell

I have a UICollectionView and there user can select on cell to use the Function in it. So and i need it to set the first cell to selected like in the First Screenshot. But the Problem there is when the cell is selected and user want to select ah other cell the first cell don´t unselect. I have try it to reload the tableview in did select item but that don´t run or with this func in viewdidload `LabelCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)`

Have anyone an idea what i can make there ? thanks for Help:)

[First Cell Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82vao.png)

[Here you see the Problem in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM7jP.png)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoryLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell


    let labels = Labels[indexPath.row]


    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    cell.Title.text = labels



    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = darkgrau
        cell.layer.borderColor = black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }


    return cell

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell


    if indexPath.row == indexPath.row {
        cell.backgroundColor = darkgrau
        cell.layer.borderColor = black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    }

}




func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell


    if indexPath.row == indexPath.row {

        cell.backgroundColor = lightGray
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with checking for `indexPath.row == indexPath.row`? Basically you can try with `cell.selected = true` when it is selected and set it to `false` when deselected. Try below code and let me know if it works.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "StoryLabelCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell

    let labels = Labels[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.Title.text = labels

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = darkgrau
        cell.layer.borderColor = black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        cell.selected = true
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell

    cell.backgroundColor = darkgrau
    cell.layer.borderColor = black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.selected = true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! StoryLabelCell

    cell.backgroundColor = lightGray
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0
    cell.selected = false
}
```

Comment: i have used to set the other cells in light gray (not selected) in the {index path.row == index path.row}else {} but it not run he give me only the selected cell. So it run all but the problem is when i want to select a other cell the first cell (what is selected) don´t go away and then two cells are selected. I must anyway change select (light gray) of the first cell when i tap on a other cell.

Comment: Yes thats how it works, you should mark it as selected = true to change the UI and set it back to false when selected other cells. Did youtry with above code?

Comment: yeah i have try it but it don´t run give it maybe a other way in didSelectItemAt ?

Comment: What error you are getting? What output you getting?

Comment: That to cells are selected when i tap on other cell index . When i tap two time on the first cell and then a other cell it run but that´s not user-friendly. So i must set the background to light gray ( not selected) when i tap a other cell in maybe in didselectItem.

Comment: this is because in your cellForItem func you set the first cell to selected, no matter what happens. If you want the fiest cell to be selected by default, than set it in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

u should use the Cells selected state instead of comparing two values that are the same.

In you custom cell you react on cell selections!

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool,  animated: Bool) {
    // change your cell like you want
    if selected {
        // make me dark
    } else { 
        // make me light
    }
    // not tested, but somehow call the super
    super.setSelected(selected:selected, animated: animated)
}
```

you can delete your didSelect and didDeselct func.

In the function cellForItem ... you can check if a cell is selected, if not select the one with indexPath.row == 0

For checking a selected cell use

```
collectionView.indexPathForSelectedItems
```

this is list, so you can select more than one cell. I am not sure, but i think u can setup the collectionView with multiple selections ore only one selection.

I hope this helps you so far.